# Why does Unity 2019 take so long to open?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the unity 2019.4.9f1 version and use Visual studio 2019 community.
Basically every time I want to open a project it could take anywhere from 3 minutes to 10 minutes to open. If opening a .cs file from Unity it would take 3 minutes to open it in Visual Studi and I guess thats normal. The task manager says its taking up 15% of my memory and my laptop is 8GB Ram, and I installed Unity on my hard disk instead of the SSD. What can I do to speed it up? And does it being on the hard disk make it slower than if it was on the SSD?

Answer (score 2):

**What can I do to speed it up?**

From my experience, a long loading time is first caused by not having enough memory available, and second, having the software and/or the project on the hard drive. Based on what you said, it seems that you are in the second case. If you want Unity and/or Visual Studio to load faster, put them both on your SSD, and also depending on the size of your project move it to your SSD too.

**And does it being on the hard disk make it slower than if it was on the SSD?**

Yes, of course, hard drives typically run 10x slower than SSDs. Usually, it is recommended to put recurrent software on the SSD to speed loading times and use the HDD for storage.